# Want to display 2 buttons vertically on top of each other, starting from the centre of the screen - only one button displays

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

This is my first time using XML and working with Android so I am truly a noob. I want to have 2 buttons; `Sign In` and `Create Account`, where `Sign In` is at the centre of the screen and `Create Account` is directly beneath it.

What I currently have is just the `Create Account` button and it's at the **top** of the screen not the centre. For some reason, `Sign In` just doesn't appear anywhere. Can somebody take a look at my XML doc and see if they can spot why this is happening?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="25dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSignIn"
    android:text="SignIn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bCreateAccount"
    android:text="Create Account"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Oh and this is the main activity (if that has any relevance). Highly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSignIn"
        android:text="SignIn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bCreateAccount"
        android:text="Create Account"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bSignIn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding a wrapper which uses`android:layout_centerInParent` in accordance to the base layout. Inside this, you could                      'android:layout_below' to achieve what you're looking for.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:padding="25dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/bSignIn"
                   android:text="SignIn"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/bCreateAccount"
                   android:text="Create Account"
                   android:layout_below="@id/bSignIn"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_below="@+id/bSignIn"` to your `bCreateAccount`.

here is the the code.

```
    <RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/bSignIn"
     android:text="SignIn"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/bCreateAccount"
     android:text="Create Account"
     android:layout_below="@+id/bSignIn"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSignIn"
        android:text="SignIn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/bCreateAccount"
        android:text="Create Account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```
android:layout_below="@id/bSignIn"
```

And change `centerHorizontal` to `centerInParent`

in the `bCreateAccount` button XML to place it below the prior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSignIn"
        android:text="SignIn"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bCreateAccount"
        android:text="Create Account"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bSignIn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```